# Transpose Column to Row SQl one row

Tags: sql, transpose

I have an sql query that is returning 12 columns with the percentage data. I would like to transpose the query to have 12 rows in one column and the % data in another column

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I would like:**

[image]

Tha nks

Comment: please kindly add the DBMS

Comment:  Please consider not posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports the [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) function, you could try this.

```
SELECT Proposal_source, [%]
from (select candidate_generator, 
             crm_srt_ui, 
             knock_on_effect, 
             matchmaker_mutator, 
             ml_models, 
             object_association, 
             script_manual_data, 
             unified_onboarding 
    from tableA) p
UNPIVOT
( [%] FOR Proposal_source in 
            (candidate_generator, 
             crm_srt_ui, 
             knock_on_effect, 
             matchmaker_mutator, 
             ml_models, 
             object_association, 
             script_manual_data, 
             unified_onboarding )
  ) as unpvt;
```

If it does not support UNPIVOT, Then you could try union all the columns together

```
SELECT 'unified_onboarding' as Proposal_source, unified_onboarding as '%' FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'script_manual_data' as Proposal_source, script_manual_data as '%' FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'matchmaker_mutator' as Proposal_source, matchmaker_mutator as '%' FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'ml_models' as Proposal_source, ml_models as '%' FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'candidate_generator' as Proposal_source, candidate_generator as '%' FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'knock_on_effect' as Proposal_source, knock_on_effect as '%' FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'crm_srt_ui' as Proposal_source, crm_srt_ui as '%' FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT 'object_association' as Proposal_source, object_association as '%' FROM tableA
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hG9RDqVb)